# The meaning of unless in sentence

Tags: mathematics

While reading a book I encountered a sentence

> For a nonzero integer n, there is an even number of positive divisors of n unless n is a perfect square

What does it mean by **unless n is a perfect square**. Also, what does "unless" mean here?

Comment: This is the usual dictionary meaning of unless https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/unless . It is a conjunction, and there is probably a reasonably straightforward gloss into your language, eg "Danish: medmindre, undtagen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here "unless" introduces an exception to the rule. *n* is used by mathematicians to mean "some whole positive number". So you could write this in two parts as:

- If *n* is not a perfect square then it has an even number of positive divisors
- If *n* is a perfect square then the number of positive divisors may be odd or even.

A *perfect square* is the square of a whole number, such as 4, 9 or 25.

Comment: I think a perfect square is n x n, so 4 is a perfect square, though 2 isn't a square of integers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, you are correct. I misread the definition. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: N is generally used to mean simply "some particular number" and whether it means an integer, a positive integer, a rational number or a member of some other restricted set is context-dependent. here N means any non-zero integer, the theorem applies to negative integers as well.